# How can I add an SSL proxy and Authentication layer for Redis

Tags: redis

As "[Redis is not optimized for maximum security but for maximum performance and simplicity](http://redis.io/topics/security)." How can I add an SSL proxy and Authentication layer for Redis ? 
Can nginx or twemproxy good for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You could use [stunnel](https://redislabs.com/blog/using-stunnel-to-secure-redis) for this purpose.
2. Recently, there has been some [talk](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/2045#issuecomment-60053527) about including OpenSSL in Redis - ETA is still unknown however.
3. Some recommend [spiped](http://www.tarsnap.com/spiped.html) instead of stunnel - it does not provide SSL but can be used to secure your connections to Redis.

Comment: stunnel is wonderful! Is it possible to use stunnel only in redis server side, and use official clients(http://redis.io/clients) in use side?

Comment: Yes, but you'll need a client that supports SSL. There are only a select few right now - see here: https://redislabs.com/blog/secure-redis-ssl-added-to-redsmin-and-clients

Answer (score -3):

ElastiCache provides Redis which supports TLS encryption in transit. No need to run a separate proxy.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/in-transit-encryption.html